# Complete shortcut in Messages on OS X

Tags: macos, messages, shortcut

Found a "Complete" shortcut in Messages on OS X under `Edit`, I want to know what it does exactly, but can't find any info. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a text autocomplete feature. You can type `when` and press `Esc` to shows all the available words. It’s available everywhere, not just **Messages**. But somehow **Messages** doesn’t act according to its function, I believe it’s a bug, or Messages uses different frameworks for the text field.

[image: Autocomplete Text]

Comment: how do you do the gif animation (with what?)

Comment: @Buscar웃 I use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea why this shortcut works with just `Esc` when it says `Option + Esc` in the menu?